# Did countries ever default against Federal Reserve's swap line?

Tags: macroeconomics, central-banking, federal-reserve, economic-history, history

Did foreign countries ever default against [Fed's swap line](https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/bst_liquidityswaps.htm) or [Foreign and International Monetary Authorities](https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fima-repo-facility.htm) ? Or is it technically possible? I guess they will lose their collateral, and it's a big reputational damage, but has it ever happened?

I am asking because Argentina has used all of its yuan swap line, and I wonder if it could default on that. Not many countries have used yuan swap lines, so I am wondering if we can find similar history with dollar swap lines.